# How to add custom js to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am using Node.js for my Web Server.
I installed [Typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/)
Now I am having poblem implementing it in my HTML file.

I used the following code in css/script.js:

```
var typed =new Typed('#typed',{
    strings: ["First sentence.", "Second sentence."],
    typeSpeed: 30
  })
```

In the HTML file :

```
<h1 id="typed"></h1>
....body....
<script src="css/script.js></script>
```

Also I included the Script file at the bottom of index.html page.
What am I doing wrong here.

**Edit:** I checked the console log it says localhost:3000/css/script.js not found. I searched a little bit came across using static files in express.js
by this method `app.use(express.static('public'))`but still shows the same error File not Found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is server-side framework, but you are just developing client-side 
logic with HTML/JavaScript here.

Are you just using package manager such as `npm` and `yarn`, but not Node.js?

You should include the Typed.js in your HTML like this:

`<script src="node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.js"></script>`